# Addclass to parent based on input condition

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, addclass

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" /> Normal</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" /> Checked</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" disabled="disabled" /> Disabled</label>
```

If the checkbox is 'checked', its label should have class 'checked', same for 'disabled'.

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
    function() { 
       $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    } 
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eJfT6/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this:

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){

        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    }

    if($(this).is(':disabled')){

        $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(
    function() {

        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');

    }
);
// for disabled 
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(
    function() {
        if( $(this).attr('disabled')){
           alert("in side");
            $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        }

    }
);
```

you can merge both function i have seprated it just for your understanding.
[**http://jsfiddle.net/Htcjb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Htcjb/)